# Are there other limits than the 1MB to write to Memcache?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a strange problem. In a task I fetch data from the datastore and write it async to memcache:

```
ke = database.Events.query(database.Events.eventid.IN(eventslist))
eventskeys = ke.fetch(len(eventslist),keys_only = True)

data = ndb.get_multi(eventskeys)

eventsdic = {}

for event in data:
    eventsdic.update({event.eventid: event.participants})

client = memcache.Client()

rpc = memcache.create_rpc()     
response = client.set_multi_async(eventsdic, time=3600, rpc=rpc)
```

The eventlist has 20 items in it. I do that for about 500 items spread out over different tasks in a queue.

I don't get any error. But I noticed, that in the first try just around 300 of 500 events are really present in the memcache after that. If I do 2-3 retries with just the events, which are not in memcache yet, I have 100% in memcache after a while.

But I don't really get, why it doesn't work with the first attempt?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because memcache "watches" your data. Frequently used items are less likely to be evicted. It's (as I understand it) not simply a FIFO type system

To me it's not a "problem" as such that if I put something into memcache it's not there when I later ask for it. I'll use the fallback mechanism I put in to cope with that situation. You simply can't assume *anything* will be in memcache when you ask for it.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/memcache

> The tradeoff is that data held in memcache is transient and is evicted as the system runs out of memcache space. On rare occasions, all memcached data can be evicted at once.

Comment: thanks - but can data be evicted just seconds after it has been written to memcache? This task already is my fallback, to restore memcache data which I found out isn't there in the first place.

Comment: I guess it can, if you are adding *loads* of content  it's going to evict some of it if it runs out of space. Fact is it's all a bit opaque  really. Try doing some tests, instead of 500 try it with 50 - see if it's all there afterwards. Even so, whatever you discover I guess might change as they shift resources around.

Comment: Also notice how it's never mentioned *how much* memcache is available to a given app?